# How to decide number of coordinating nodes in our elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a huge elasticsearch cluster with ~400 nodes (3 master, 5 coordinating nodes). During our last load test, we saw that one of the coordinating node had high latency and FD count was also spiking.
I checked CPU usage, disk utilisation and jvm memory, all seems to be balanced for all coordinating nodes.

First, what could cause a dis balanced FD count among coordinating nodes? Could it be a problem with the machine itself? `considering coor nodes themselves are intelligent load balancers`

Machine behaving abruptly had 22k fd count (*max:65k*), could this be the issue? I believe there must be some other underlying resource being choked

What other metrics should I focus on when deciding the number of coordinating nodes in an ES cluster

Comment: data nodes: 32c64gb
coor nodes:16c32gb

Comment: What happen if you remove this node from the cluster?
If another node start to be with hgigh latency it look like you have some proccess, that use huge compute requirements. If no it look like node problem.

Comment: You can check the tasks in your nodes with tasks API for current node, using 
GET _tasks/node_id?deatiled=true

Comment: High Compute requirements would be visible in the CPU usage of the machine, but CPU remained ~65, similar to all other coors in the system. 

I can check this during next load test, if there were any processes running on the specific node.

Comment: It's not only CPU. Pay attention to heap usage too. And one more things, do you set the memlock in the configuration: bootstrap.memory_lock: true ?  Is the swap disabled in the servers?

Comment: Heap is fine for all servers, memory_lock is also set to true